# How do I prevent HTML encoding of '&' characters while copying content from a div to the title of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, encoding, character-encoding

I have a div whose contents are My Home & Administration
    `<div id="abc"> My Home & Administration></div>`

In the scripts, I need to copy the contents of this div to my page title. Currently I am using innerHTML property which encodes the value.

```
<script type="text/javascript>
var id = document.getElementById("abc");
document.title = id.innerHTML;
</script>
```

The title is displayed as **My Home & amp; Administration** 
(Note: disregard the space between & and amp;)

Is there any alternate way where the title is displayed as is?
**I cannot use JQuery or any frameworks apart from pure and simple Javascript**

Also note that this is not URL encoding but rather conversion of characters to their HTML entities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML`.

`.innerHTML` is actually not part of the DOM spec. Most browsers offer it as a non-standard feature. There are several problems with `.innerHTML`.

Since you're interested in the actual text value of the node you can use `.textContent`.

It might be useful to know that the `div` *abc* actually has a node inside it, a `TextNode`, which holds the value. The `div` itself doesn't actually hold the value. If you were to traverse the DOM you would see this text node.

If your HTML is:

```
<div id="abc">Foo <strong>bar</strong> baz</div>
```

Your structure will be:

```
`div`:abc
  TextNode Foo
  `strong`
    TextNode bar
  TextNode baz
```

In this case `abc.textContent` will return `"Foo bar baz"` so it ignores the `strong` tag.

In comparison `.innerHTML` will return `"Foo <strong>bar</strong> baz"`

Similarly for:

```
<div id="abc">Foo&amp;Bar</div>
```

`.textContent` will be `"Foo&Bar"`, `.innerHTML` will be `"Foo&amp;Bar"`