# Trying to understand this JavaScript behavior with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to set the less-than symbol and the less-than or equal symbol using `innerHTML`, then get the encoded text back out, not the decoded symbols.

This works with `&lt;`, but not with `&le;`. Is there a reason why this would be?

```
var lt = '&lt;';
var le = '&le;';

var div_lt = document.createElement('div');
div_lt.setAttribute('original_value', lt);
div_lt.innerHTML = lt;

var div_le = document.createElement('div');
div_le.setAttribute('original_value', le);
div_le.innerHTML = le;

console.log([div_lt.innerHTML, div_lt.innerText, div_lt.getAttribute('original_value')]);
// gives [ "&lt;", "<", "&lt;" ], as I expected
console.log([div_le.innerHTML, div_le.innerText, div_le.getAttribute('original_value')]);
// gives [ "≤", "≤", "&le;" ], but the first value should be "&le;"
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/54m6c8sk/

Comment: `&le;` is a **HTML5 special entity**, while `&lt;` works in HTML4 as well. This may do something with the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML `<` means "Start of tag" and `≤` means "≤".

When you want to express `<` in HTML then you often *must* use an entity. When you want to express `≤`, you *never* have to use an entity.

Converting DOM to HTML via `innerHTML` doesn't convert `≤` to `&le;` because it is never useful to do so.

Comment: One thing I do want to add to your helpful answer is that in ASCII `≤` is not available, so unless the file encoding supports using it directly, `&le;` must be used.

Answer (score -2):

This is a fun one... but already answered: [How do I prevent HTML encoding of '&' characters while copying content from a div to the title of the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29562648/how-do-i-prevent-html-encoding-of-characters-while-copying-content-from-a-di)

tldr: use textContent instead of innerHTML -- innerHTML is actually not part of the DOM spec

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17321771)

Comment: Question: "why is this happening"
Answer: "because innerHTML does that -- here's the right way to approach this issue" AND a link to an in-depth discussion on this exact topic.
What am I missing?

Comment: "Answer: "because innerHTML does that" — That isn't what this answer says. It says "Follow this link and read the answer somewhere else".

Comment: "here's the right way to approach this issue" — That gives precisely the opposite effect to what the OP wants.

Comment: "innerHTML is actually not part of the DOM spec" — What does that have to do with anything? [There is a spec for it](https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#dom-element-innerhtml).

Comment: The technical correctness of this answer aside (I don't know enough to judge), please don't post answers that consist of little more than a link to other Stack Overflow questions. Instead, flag this question as a duplicate of the other question.

Comment: I don't see a flag option. Presumably I'm too new for that, too. I can see my career of answering stackoverflow questions will be short lived.

Comment: @bluejack. Sorry for the terseness in my original comment, it's an auto generated comment from the Stackoverflow queue that we watch for flagged questions and answers. It is a shame that there is an inability to see the flagging feature on the questions when you lack the fake internet points. Generally speaking an answer containing a link that will avoid flagging will elaborate on the contents of that link as links often die. Each Q&A on here should be complete in and of itself for future searchers. Sorry again for the robotic comment.